# Do I need to (re-)partition my SD card for app2sd to work?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, external-sd, app2sd

I have a rooted HTC Hero, currently running VillainRom (Android 2.1). I want to install FroydVillain (Android 2.2), which supports app2sd, but I'm not sure whether I need to repartition my SD card before I install 2.2 and if yes, how, if I want app2sd to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The CyanogenMod wiki has some info on this](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/Apps2SD).

Basically, their old version of apps2sd (now called apps2ext) required an EXT partition on the SD card.

Their current version does not require partitioning, it's just a matter of overriding the preference of the app and moving it to the SD card anyways.

Since FroydVillain is based on CM6, you don't need to format your SD card; CM6+ uses the new apps2sd, not apps2ext.